# Какие есть хуки/фильтры для указания скидки товару woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

Всем привет!
Вопрос на засыпку: какие есть хуки/фильтры для указания скидки товару?
Т.е. задача такая: надо сделать так, чтобы при определенном количестве товаров в корзине, ко всем товарам применялась скидка.

Плагины какие-то все бестолковые, а зацепок, где можно было-бы правильно применять скидку с правилом товарам wc мне найти не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, спасибо, разобрался!
Шучу :)

Помог вот этот хук - woocommerce_before_calculate_totals

И вот эта [статья](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/change-product-prices-in-cart.html)

Самое главное ведь то, чтобы в корзине в итоге всё считалось правильно и падало в заказ. А если есть онлайн-оплата - то и туда важно чтобы ценник правильный падал. Собственно, в этой статье всё и описано, как это сделать. А если нужно выводить скидки у карточек товаров такие, то там уже надо дополнительно функцию делать, которая покажет юзеру правильную цену со скидкой.